# $S_n=x^n+y^n+z^n$. If $S_1=0$, find $m$ such that $S_pS_q=mS_{p+q}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

$S_n=x^n+y^n+z^n$ $(x\neq y\neq z\neq 0)$. If $\space S_1=0, \space$ find $\space m \space$ such that  $$S_pS_q=mS_{p+q}$$
I thought of this problem while solving a particular case in which $\space p=2 \space$ and $\space q=5$. I got $\space m= \frac{10}{7}. \space$ I tried for $\space p=2 \space$ and $\space q=3 \space$ and got $m= \frac{5}{6}. \space$
My question is how can we get a General expression for $\space m \space$ (in terms of $\space p \space$ and $\space q$)?

Comment: For a pair $(p,q)\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\times\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, if $m$ exists, then $m$ can be calculated by taking $(x,y,z)=(2,-1,-1)$, making $$m=\frac{\left(2^p+2(-1)^p\right)(2^q+2(-1)^q)}{2^{p+q}+2(-1)^{p+q}}\,.$$  However, not every pair $(p,q)$ has such a constant $m$.   Pairs $(p,q)$ that do not work are, for example, $$(2,4)\text{ and }(3,3)\,.$$   Some pairs $(p,q)$ with $2\leq p\leq q$ which work are $$(2,2),(2,3),\text{ and }(2,5)\,.$$  Any pair $(p,q)$ with $p=1$ or $q=1$ always works by taking $m=0$.  I conjecture that my list of pairs $(p,q)$ with $p\leq q$ that work is complete.

Comment: We must also have $x \neq z$; and $x$, $y$, and $z$ must **all** be nonzero. The relation "is not equal to" is not transitive.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang  That is an unnecessary condition.  If $S_pS_q=mS_{p+q}$ for all $(x,y,z)$ such that $x\ne y\ne z\ne x$ and $x+y+z=0$, then this is a polynomial identity in $x$ and $y$ (by setting $z=-x-y$).  Thus, the relation $S_pS_q=mS_{p+q}$ will hold even if some variables are equal, as long as the condition $x+y+z=0$ is true.